# display the selected node from the treeview in the textbox?

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a treeview for show the contact details of customer.

I bring contact details into `treeview` but if i click any customer name it would show customers details in seperate textboxes like, `firstname`, `lastname`, `personal email`, `office email`,it will go upto 17 data's.

Please any one help how to solve this problem.

Here is example image what i want to exactly

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SelectedNode` property of the treeview to get the text of the selected node.

```
textBox1.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
```

To get the text of the child of the selected node, you can use

```
textBox1.Text = treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes["NodeName"].Text;
```

Comment: I think the OP is also looking for how to put the children's data in to their own textboxes as well.

Comment: @paqogomez Well that isn't what he said? but I added it to my answer. Just in case

Comment: @paqogomez thank u for your reply..but what i want is the selected value is only the datatables first data....i need to display all the column value to corresponding textboxes(near to 17 texboxes and 17 columns value in datatable) when i select tree view's node....

Comment: @DharaniRadhakrishnanR I really don't get what you want. You want to display the data in the **all** treeview's nodes once you select a node?

Comment: @Christmas Unicorn Sir, that selected value is taken from datatable's first column value...datatable contains all users details into table if click selected value from treeview controls node, i should show the corresponding table column value on each texbox... like the process is shown in image

Comment: @DharaniRadhakrishnanR, Mr. Unicorn's answer does this.  if you replace "NodeName" with "Address" and "phone" etc, and point that value at their respective text boxes it will work.

Comment: @paqogomez I used that above code but it show the Exception error of object reference is null

Comment: Do you have a selected node?

Comment: You should put his code in the selected event of your tree.  Then you can be assured of a selected node.